# Using Intl format number to format number with 1 decimal but not for 0

Tags: javascript

I would like to format numbers adding always 1 decimal but not for `0`.

I'm using `Intl.NumberFormat` and I'm wondering if there is an option that allow to avoid adding decimal only for `0` number.

```js
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  minimumFractionDigits: 1,
  maximumFractionDigits: 1
});

function format(value) {
  console.log(`${value} -> ${formatter.format(value)}`)
}

format(11.29);
format(11);
format(0); // I would like to have "0", not "0.0"
```

Comment: You can put condition inside format function for value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  maximumFractionDigits: 1,
  minimumFractionDigits: 1
});

function format(value) {
  if (value === 0) return console.log(`${value} -> ${Math.trunc(value)}`)
  console.log(`${value} -> ${formatter.format(value)}`)
}

format(11.29);
format(11);
format(0); // I would like to have "0", not "0.0"
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work as I need because 11.29 -> 10 and 11 -> 10

Comment: @whitecircle apologies, updated now so it should work

Comment: Mmm no, I always want decimal, except for 0

Comment: @whitecircle updated to reflect your needs